# Problems with sum functions

Tags: r, sum, rcpp, parallels

Using other programming language to accelerate R is a big innovation, but seems hazardous as well. Any statistic function had to be stable to use, given the same result for the same entry such as `sum`, `sd`, `cor`...
The problem I have is with using big amount of data (10^8 sample). I used RCPP and RCPPPARALLEL version of sum to demonstrate bugs for big data.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
/********************************************************
 *           Rcpp inner function :sum
 *******************************************************/
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double RCPPSUM(NumericVector x) {
  return sum(x);
}

/*** R


library("Rcpp")
library("RcppParallel")
  options(digits=22)# showing more details in number  
  sourceCpp(system.file("tests/cpp/sum.cpp", package = "RcppParallel"))
##  Given two function parallelVectorSum  (RcppParallel) and vectorSum (C++STL)
##  We manipulated a very big vector
  x<-rnorm(100000000)
  (RSUM<-sum(x))
  (RCPP<-RCPPSUM(x))
  (RCPPPARALLEL<-parallelVectorSum(x))
  (STD<-vectorSum(x))
  identical(RSUM,RCPP)
  identical(STD,RCPP)
  identical(RSUM,RCPPPARALLEL)
  identical(RCPP,RCPPPARALLEL)
## Simple checking of stability
  v<-0
for(i in 1:100)v[i]<-sum(x)
  (mean(v))
  (sd(v))
####stable sd =0
  for(i in 1:100)v[i]<-vectorSum(x)
    (mean(v))
    (sd(v))
###stable sd =0
  for(i in 1:100)v[i]<-RCPPSUM(x)
  (mean(v))
  (sd(v))
###stable sd =0

  for(i in 1:100)v[i]<-parallelVectorSum(x)
  (mean(v))
  (sd(v))
##instable sd!=0
      */
```

We can qualify parallel version as unstable, so it is excluded.
Which result between RCPP and RSUM is really the truth?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: There different results for the same function

Comment: You are bound to hit roundoff errors when summing this many numbers. Even the built-in `sum` function will not give the same answer when the input is shuffled: `identical(sum(x),sum(rev(x)))` yields `FALSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly:

1. Conjecture alert:  *seems hazardous as well*. Please back this up or remove it.
2. Please show the courtesy of proper capitalization. We write this as `Rcpp` and `RcppParallel`, respectively. Though I guess you just refer to labels so it doesn't really matter.
3. Using `options(digits=22)` is cute but useless. Double precision gives you around 16 digits. Just hoping for more does not give you more.